# How to put a parameter into an query in SSRS 2008 R2 connected to an Oracle Database 11g

Tags: oracle, reporting-services, parameters

Putting a parameter into the query gets the following error:

```
"ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number"
```

The query is:

```
select * from t_accounts where account_number = @ReportParamter1
```

Without the where clause, the query runs fine

Any ideas?

thanx!

Abraham

Answer (score 8):

Oracle wants its bound parameters to be denoted with colons, not @ signs.
So you want

```
...where account_number = :ReportParamter1
```

Answer (score 0):

O. Jones highlighted the root but didn't go into as much detail as I needed to address this same issue/question. I had created the parameter in Visual Studio and as noted it has the '@' in the format of the parameter so when applied to the Dataset I got the error message. Unfortunately in the construct of the parameter in VS (I'm using 12) there isn't anything in the various options that allows designating a : in place of the @. What I discovered was after manually adding the parameter to my query in the Dataset, I then found it listed in the parameters area of the Dataset Properties - the parameter entered in query was set to the parameter made in VS. I removed the original and preview processed without issue.